# Heroku SSL Certificate does not include cname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https

I have an app on heroku (guestlist12.herokuapp.com) and I've added the domain guestlist.ch.
I've done that via cname www.guestlist.ch => guestlist12.herokuapp.com as I cannot move my DNS away from where it is right now.

How do I fix the problem with the SSL cert? Right now, whenever I access the page, I get an error because the cert is not equal to the name of the page. How can I configure Heroku or my app so that this doesn't happen?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku's wildcard certificate is only valid for `*.herokuapp.com`.

You have to set up your own SSL certificate for custom domains:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#customdomain-ssl